# How can I convert time to seconds when the seconds are formatted in 3 digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

Say I have this time

```
00:46:19,870
```

where it represents `46h 19m` and 870 is `870/1000` of a minute (I think I can just get rid of the last part). How do I convert this to seconds?

I've tried

```
time.strptime('00:46:19,870'.split(',')[0],'%H:%M:%S')
```

but realized that it wouldn't work as it's using a format different than mine.

How can I convert `00:46:19,870` to `2779`?

Comment: What data type is "this time" you have?

Comment: That's an odd representation. Times don't usually include a number of days like this appears to. I think you're going to have to split the string manually first, to get `'46:19'` and `870` in separate strings.

Comment: Are you *positive* that `"00:46:19,870"` is `46h 19m 870/1000s`? That is a really strange representation, I would strongly suspect that is `00h 46m 19.870s'

Answer (score 0):

You are close, you can still use the `datetime` you just need to calculate the time delta. What you really have isn't really a date but what appears to be a stopwatch time time. You can still strip the time from that and you will notice that Python uses a default year, month, and day. You can use that default to figure out the delta in seconds:

```py
from datetime import datetime

DEFAULT_DATE = (1900, 1, 1)

stopwatch = datetime.strptime('00:46:19,870', '%H:%M:%S,%f')

a_timedelta = stopwatch - datetime(*DEFAULT_DATE)
seconds = a_timedelta.total_seconds()

print(seconds)
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP claims the string represents. It's not 46 minutes, 19.870 seconds, but 46 hours, 19.87 minutes.

Comment: @chepner I do indeed see that however look at the `strptime` expression they currently uses. Also look at their desired output which matches the output of my code. Agree he has a typo but the answer still fits his desired output.

Comment: I think only because there are 60 minutes in an hour and 60 seconds in a minute. If the first field is ever something other than 0, it's not going to translate correctly (because there are 24 hours in a day, not 60.)